# How to properly display a price up to two decimals (cents) including trailing zeros in Java?

Tags: java, double, rounding, decimal-point

There is a good question on rounding decimals in Java [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java). But I was wondering how can I include the trailing zeros to display prices in my program like: $1.50, $1.00

The simple solution of

```
String.format("%.2g%n", 0.912385);
```

works just fine, but omits the trailing zero if it is at the last decimal place. The issue comes up in my program even though I only use expressions like this:

```
double price = 1.50;
```

When I do calculations with different prices (add, multiply, etc.) the result is primarily displayed like this:

```
$2.5000000000000003
```

So, using the String.format works fine for this purpose, but it truncates the above example to

```
$2.5
```

Is there a proper way to show the trailing zero at the second decimal place? Or both zeros if the output of a calculation should be

```
$2.00
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, never use floating point numbers to represent currency. Instead consider using an integer for the cents / pence.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would recommend that you do this:

```
NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
double price = 2.50000000000003;
System.out.println(currencyFormatter.format(price));
```

This has the virtue of be locale-specific as well.  This will work, for example, if you're in the euro zone instead of the US.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like that! I didn't know of the getCurrencyInstance() method.

Answer (score 14):

While others answers are perfectly valid (especially duffymo's one), you have a much bigger problem than formatting the display. You are actually using a totally **wrong** type for a money amount which is a *discrete* value. Instead of a `double`, you should really consider using a [`java.lang.BigDecimal`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

(EDIT: ... or a well implemented Money class as duffymo pointed out in a comment, for example classes from JScience's [monetary](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/economics/money/package-summary.html#package_description) module or the more recent [Joda-Money](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/) - which has still to be released as an official version.)

Comment: +1 - excellent point.  Either BigDecimal or a proper Money class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Point taken :)

Answer (score 11):

It can probably be done with String.format(...), but you could use [`DecimalFormat`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
double price = 2.50000000000003;
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
System.out.println(formatter.format(price)); // print: $2.50
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
String s = String.format("$%.2f", 2.50);
```

That will do the trick.

Comment: Although my answer accomplishes what you requested, the better solution, as others have noted, is to use `BigDecimal` or a true Money class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getFormattedData(String actualString) 
    {
        String subString = "0.0";

        if(actualString.contains("."))
        {   
            subString = actualString.substring(actualString.indexOf("."), actualString.trim().length()); 

            if(Double.parseDouble(subString) > 0.0)
                return actualString;
            else
                actualString = actualString.substring(0, actualString.indexOf("."));
        }
        return actualString;
    }
```