# decimal points precision is lost for some munbers in case of double data type

Tags: java, double

I am suprise to see the below program please advise how it is behaving like this as i aam very much concerened with poitn to precison after decimal point  , below is the progrmam

```
double fixedRate = 0.997500000000;  //**output --->0.9975
    //  BigDecimal fixedRate = new BigDecimal("0.997500000000");        
        double fixedRate1 = 0.1234567890123456789;  

        System.out.println(fixedRate);
        System.out.println(fixedRate1);
```

and the output is

```
0.9975
0.12345678901234568
```

now please advise for the first the ouput is 0.9975 but late on for next it is not truncating after decimal points but why for first then.

Comment: Have a look at the tutorial on how to format numbers https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: no that is different thing i agree Thanks for th advise

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html read and reread until you understand fully

Answer (score 0):

```
This is a printing problem.Please use this format to print your values and tell me the result: 

double fixedRate = 0.997500000000;
double fixedRate1 = 0.1234567890123456789; 

System.out.println(String.format("%.19f", fixedRate ));
System.out.println(String.format("%.19f", fixedRate1 ));

Good Luck !
```

Comment: @user1508454.. Please use this :

System.out.println(String.format("%.19f", fixedRate ));
System.out.println(String.format("%.19f", fixedRate1 ));

Comment: @user1508454 ..it means you should set the deciminal places at your wish. E.g .. %.2f, %3.f , %4.f and for your case I think it is %19.f.

Answer (score 0):

The precision is not *lost*. It is just not printed because you do not need more digits to distinguish the printed value from any other double value.

If you do want to force a certain number of fractional digits, take a look at **System.out.printf()** or **String.format()**.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html for more details and possible formats.

The result may look like this:

```
            System.out.printf("%.19f%n",fixedRate);
            System.out.printf("%.19f%n", fixedRate1);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question

> for the first the ouput is 0.9975 but late on for next it is not
>   truncating after decimal points but why for first then

Since `double` is numeric datatype and hence cannot hold the leading and trailing zeros.

A `double` doesn't care about formatting - it's about storage only. When you print it, it is converted to a String (using `Double`'s static [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)) method).

In simple terms the value `0.9975` is not different from `0.997500000000`or it is same as `0.997500000000` as zeros after a number will not have any value.

But consider if you had value like this `0.9975000000001` then all the numbers will be printed. Check it [here](http://ideone.com/P5NTwA).

If you want to format the value then you can see this question : [How to properly display a price up to two decimals (cents) including trailing zeros in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734282/how-to-properly-display-a-price-up-to-two-decimals-cents-including-trailing-ze)